# Java: JSON String -> LIST OF Protobuf

Tags: java, list, protocol-buffers

```
JsonFormat.parser().merge(json_string, builder);
```

I know that I can use the above code for turning a json string into a Protobuf java object. But what if my json_string has multiple items (list) and I want to turn it into LIST OF Protobuf java objects?

For example my json string being:

```
[
  {"id": 1},
  {"id": 2},
  {"id": 3}
]
```

how can I turn this into a List containing 3 Protobuf objects in java?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a feature as such, because [JsonFormat](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat) is designed specifically to match the [canonical proto3 JSON mapping](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json), which does not have any concept of "top-level" arrays, only arrays for representing repeated fields.

That said, likely-to-work (though annoyingly inelegant) workarounds include at least:

**Using a wrapper message with a repeated field**

If you define a wrapper message that just contains a single repeated field holding your actual payload message:

```proto
message Item {
  int64 id = 1;
}

message ItemList {
  repeated Item items = 1;
}
```

You could parse your JSON array into a list by surrounding it with the necessary bits to make it a valid instance of your wrapper message:

```java
ItemList.Builder builder = ItemList.newBuilder();
JsonFormat.parser().merge("{\"items\":" + json_string + "}", builder);
List<Item> items = builder.getItemsList();
```

Using the [overload of the `merge` method that takes a `java.io.Reader`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.Parser.html#merge-java.io.Reader-com.google.protobuf.Message.Builder-), you could probably accomplish this without actually concatenating any strings (in case it's a very large message and that matters), though it would need something similar to the [SequenceReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/SequenceReader.html), which doesn't exist in the standard library.

**Using a separate JSON library**

The API would depend on which one of them you pick, but chances are many of them would allow you to:

1. Read in the JSON array.
2. Iterate over the array items as JSON objects.
3. Serialize the object back into a buffer.
4. Use `JsonFormat` to parse the individual objects.